# Query regarding Cloudera Manager on EC2

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I have some query regarding Cloudera Manager(Free Edition) on EC2. I am not sure this is the correct place to ask the question. If I am wrong please also let me know. Is there a place where I can put my questions regarding cloudera manager and Hadoop?

Current I am creating hadoop cluster using cloudera manager. I have m3.Xlarge EC2 Instances but the wizard does not have option to select m3.xlarge instance. Secondly, I have RHEL OS where as wizard does not have option for RHEL it has only Ubuntu 12.04 and Cent OS 6.3. Does that means it does not have support for RHEL?

Answer (score 1):

Cloudera Manager only supports ubuntu and centos as of now. And please not whatever other instances, you might have created will not be used by the cloudera manager. It will automatically create new instances and you can check that in the management console of aws. So when you choose number of instances and type of instances( only supported type by cloudera manager is available), it will use your key and secret key to create them automatically.